# What is the best way to enforce required fields are not null in a model in c#?

Tags: c#, parameters, model

I have a model that is being used that has optional and required parameters. What is the best way to ensure that the required parameters are being filled without using a DLL or library code? I need to do this straight in the model class. I was hoping to be able to use something like [Required] above each parameter that is required but it doesn't seem to exist in C#.

Am I missing something or is the only way to enforce this is to require the required parameters during instancing?

```
public class MyClassItem(RequiredParam1 Param1, RequiredParam2 Param2)
{
/* Set Parameters here */
}
```

Comment: Easiest way is a simple if statement that would throw an [`ArgumentNullException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It's just one mouse click with resharper,  i don't know about any attributes doing this thing.

Comment: Create a constructor with parameters for required parameters.  Then test in constructor that parameters are not null.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this answer assumes ASP.Net MVC framework because of the `model` tag description.

> I was hoping to be able to use something like [Required] above each
>   parameter that is required but it doesn't seem to exist in C#.

I assume that by "parameter" you actually mean "property".

You can use the [RequiredAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) in System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations to do this,

Your class would then be like:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class MyClassItem
{
    [Required]
    public Param1 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Param2 { get; set; }
}
```

You can then check this in your controller with `ModelState.IsValid`

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to go about it, is to check the arguments and throw an `ArgumentNullException` if they are `null` (I even have a code snippet for that to make my work easier):

```
public class MyClassItem(RequiredParam1 Param1, RequiredParam2 Param2)
{
    if (Param1 == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Param1));
    }
    if (Param2 == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Param2));
    }
    /* Set Parameters here */
}
```

This is such an established approach, that [Code Contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808(v=vs.110).aspx) recognize these checks at the beginning of a method as a precondition.

Talking about code contracts: Naturally, the described `null` checks work only at runtime. If you install Code Contracts, there will be a static checker that can check these kind of preconditions at compile time:

```
public class MyClassItem(RequiredParam1 Param1, RequiredParam2 Param2)
{
    Contract.Requires(Param1 != null);
    Contract.Requires(Param2 != null);
    /* Set Parameters here */
}
```

As already mentioned, the static checker would also recognize the first implementation if they are at the beginning of the method and have following calls to `Contract`:

```
public class MyClassItem(RequiredParam1 Param1, RequiredParam2 Param2)
{
    if (Param1 == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Param1));
    }
    if (Param2 == null) {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(Param2));
    }
    Contract.EndContractBlock();
    /* Set Parameters here */
}
```

Static checking means that if it is clear at compile time that one of the parameters would be `null`, the static checker will issue a warning at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you  want  To generate an area where you can specify a description for the function and each parameter for the function,
type

### ///

on the line before your function and hit (Enter)